# Having problems with getting a count in a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 5 tables as follows:

- files
- tags
- profiles
- j_file_tags
- j_profile_tags

So files can have tags, profiles give access to certain tags.

I put together two queries that do the following:

1. get a list of files that a specific profile has access to (the profile must have access to all tags a file might have)
2. get a list of tags that the profile has access to and where there is at least a file in that tag.

What I need for query 2 is a count of how many files are in a tag.

Here's the table structure and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
`id`  int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`fileName`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`empID`  int(4) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `j_file_tags` (
`id`  int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`fileID`  int(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`tagID`  int(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `j_profile_tags` (
`id`  int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`profileID`  int(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`tagID`  int(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
`id`  int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`profileName`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
`id`  int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`tagName`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic;

INSERT INTO `files` VALUES ('1', 'FileOne', '1');
INSERT INTO `files` VALUES ('2', 'FileTwo', '1');
INSERT INTO `files` VALUES ('3', 'FileThree', '1');
INSERT INTO `files` VALUES ('4', 'FileFour', '2');
INSERT INTO `files` VALUES ('5', 'FileFive', '2');
INSERT INTO `files` VALUES ('6', 'FileSix', '2');
INSERT INTO `files` VALUES ('7', 'FileSeven', '2');

INSERT INTO `profiles` VALUES ('1', 'ProfileOne');
INSERT INTO `profiles` VALUES ('2', 'ProfileTwo');
INSERT INTO `profiles` VALUES ('3', 'ProfileThree');

INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES ('1', 'TagOne');
INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES ('2', 'TagTwo');
INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES ('3', 'TagThree');
INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES ('4', 'TagFour');
INSERT INTO `tags` VALUES ('5', 'TagFive');

INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('1', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('2', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('3', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('4', '2', '5');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('5', '3', '1');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('6', '3', '3');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('7', '3', '6');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('8', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('9', '4', '1');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('10', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('11', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO `j_file_tags` VALUES ('12', '5', '6');

INSERT INTO `j_profile_tags` VALUES ('1', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `j_profile_tags` VALUES ('2', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `j_profile_tags` VALUES ('3', '1', '4');
INSERT INTO `j_profile_tags` VALUES ('4', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `j_profile_tags` VALUES ('5', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `j_profile_tags` VALUES ('6', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `j_profile_tags` VALUES ('7', '2', '4');
INSERT INTO `j_profile_tags` VALUES ('8', '2', '5');
INSERT INTO `j_profile_tags` VALUES ('9', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `j_profile_tags` VALUES ('10', '1', '5');
```

Here are my 2 queries:

```
/* Get list of files: limit by specific employee AND by tags the use has access to  */
SELECT 
    `files`.`id`,
    `files`.`fileName`,
    `files`.`empID`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`tags`.`id`)  SEPARATOR ', ') as `FileTags`
FROM `files`
LEFT JOIN `j_file_tags` ON `j_file_tags`.`fileID` = `files`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `j_file_tags`.`tagID`
WHERE
    `files`.`empID` = 1
    AND
    `j_file_tags`.`tagID` IN (1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY 
    `files`.`id`
HAVING 
    COUNT(`j_file_tags`.`id`) = (SELECT COUNT(`j_file_tags`.`id`) FROM `j_file_tags` WHERE `j_file_tags`.`fileID` = `files`.`id` );

/* SECOND QUERY where i need help */
SELECT 
    `tags`.`id`,
    `tags`.`tagName`,
    '1' as `fileCount` /* i need this to be an actual count */
FROM
    `tags`
LEFT JOIN `j_file_tags` ON `j_file_tags`.`tagID` = `tags`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `files` ON `files`.`id` = `j_file_tags`.`fileID`
LEFT JOIN `j_profile_tags` ON `j_profile_tags`.`tagID` = `tags`.`id`
WHERE
    `j_profile_tags`.`profileID` = 1
    AND 
    `files`.`empID` = 1
GROUP BY
    `tags`.`id`;
/* the fileCount column would need to say for TagOne - 2, for TagThree - 2 and for TagFive - 1 */
```

In the sample data the first query returns:

- | 1 | FileOne | 1 | 1, 3
- | 2 | FileTwo | 1 | 3, 1, 5

The second query returns:

- | 1 | TagOne    | should return 2
- | 3 | TagThree  | should return 2
- | 5 | TagFive|   | should return 1

Comment: Unless I missed something, your question is rather simple : _**What I need for query 2 is a count of how many files are in a tag.**_ The issue is that the result I see isn't what you expect: For Tag1, Tag3, Tag5 I count respectively `3,3,1` and you expect `2,2,1`... why? please clarify [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb659/18)

Comment: Yes, I expect 2,2,1 because of what the first query does. Basically, permissions. Overall, for that employee, there are 3,3,1 files BUT I have access to fewer files because of my profile. The first query returns 2 files because that's what I have access to, and I'm concatenating the related tag ids for illustration purposes. So I need to count the files in that context NOT everything in the files table.

Comment: So if i create a tag cloud it would say TagOne (2), TagThree(2), TagFive (1) and then from there the user can click "TagThree" and just see those files. If the tag cloud says TagThree(3)  and they click it and see only 2 files it would be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple the HAVING clause that you have in the first query is throwing off your results because there are truly 3 files with tags 1 and 3. I would suggest removing it all together or figuring out another way to do it.  I rewrote your query below to display your desired result, however it is not a fix all.

SELECT 
    `tags`.`id`,
    `tags`.`tagName`,
    count(fileID) as 'fileCount'
FROM `files`
LEFT JOIN `j_file_tags` ON `j_file_tags`.`fileID` = `files`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `j_file_tags`.`tagID`
WHERE
    `files`.`empID` = 1
    AND
    `j_file_tags`.`tagID` IN (1,2,3,4,5)
    AND
    fileID IN (1,2)
GROUP BY 
    `tags`.`id`

Comment: That seems to work but you're calling out the two files specifically by id. So I would image I need to run my first query inside of that "in" statement. Not sure how efficient that might be.

Comment: The reason for the "having" clause is to get an exact match on all tags a file might have. I don't believe there's a work around for that. If fileTwo has tags 1,3,5 I have to make sure the profile as access to all three of them not just one or two of the 1,3,5 tags.

Comment: I am confused to why you are calling a variable such as id from the files table from the subquery that you created in your having clause? is there another way to check this?

Comment: COUNT(j_file_tags.id) - this gives me the number of tags a file has when the profile is taken into consideration

(SELECT COUNT(j_file_tags.id) FROM j_file_tags WHERE j_file_tags.fileID = files.id) - this gives me the total number of tags the file has

These two counts have to match exactly for the user to have access to a file. Otherwise a profile that has access just to TagOne and not to TagThree would get to see FileOne anyway. - can it be done differently? maybe, but this is the most elegant, quick and accurate way to get the the files a profile has access to.

Comment: After reviewing the EER Diagram there is no way to tell what profile a employee is given.  place a field in the profiles table or make a new table called j_employee_profile otherwise your logic will not work well and will always have problems.